# Does "Placing binaries" mean building k8s successfully?

Tags: kubernetes, mesos

I follow this [Getting started with Kubernetes on Mesos](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/mesos.html) to try to build `Kubernetes-Mesos`:

> git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes
>    cd kubernetes
>       export KUBERNETES_CONTRIB=mesos
>       make

But executing `make`, it outputs following log:

```
$ make
hack/build-go.sh
+++ [1204 04:38:23] Building go targets for linux/amd64:
    cmd/kube-proxy
    cmd/kube-apiserver
    cmd/kube-controller-manager
    cmd/kubelet
    cmd/kubemark
    cmd/hyperkube
    cmd/linkcheck
    plugin/cmd/kube-scheduler
    contrib/mesos/cmd/k8sm-scheduler
    contrib/mesos/cmd/k8sm-executor
    contrib/mesos/cmd/k8sm-controller-manager
    contrib/mesos/cmd/km
    cmd/kubectl
    cmd/integration
    cmd/gendocs
    cmd/genkubedocs
    cmd/genman
    cmd/mungedocs
    cmd/genbashcomp
    cmd/genconversion
    cmd/gendeepcopy
    cmd/genswaggertypedocs
    examples/k8petstore/web-server/src
    github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo
    test/e2e/e2e.test
+++ [1204 04:38:34] Placing binaries
$
```

So is the build success or not? I can't find useful prompt info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that indicates a successful build.